# Convert a list of string into a vector

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given:

`['1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1']`

How can I convert it (efficiently) to be a vector of integers something like:

`[1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    return [int(n)
            for n in s.split()]
```